# Agorithm Grid Placing Cubes UE4

Tags: algorithm, math, grid, unreal-engine4

I have a Grid at the moment where i want to place Cubes some are filled and some are only half Cubes for the Outline of it. 
What i want to get at end is a Island shaped Plattform random generated.

But i dont know how to place them. Thought about setting Points so i get a Form and then using a kind of Pathfinding algorithm ?

Maybe someone here can help me out or know a idea way or something which could help.

Thanks

I added a Image how it should look at the end. And my Cubes to place are procuderal generated Meshs with a float input for the front vertices.

[image: Grid Image]

Comment: What are your requirements for the shape? It isn't very clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Tau Island shape like on my image

Comment: Yes, but how is that shape defined? By your literal line drawing? By a distance function? By a random boundary? How is the boundary defined? Does the island need to be connected or can it be in different parts? How jagged or smooth can the bounday be? We can't help you with these kinds of arbitrary design decisions.

Comment: @Tau That is the Point i need to know how i define this. There is no like texture or something which is defining it. It could be different Parts ofc but for atm i want it connected.  And it should be smooth,.

Comment: @Tau Do you have Discord or something then i can maybe explain you detailed what i mean cause dont wanna post everything here and it would be maybe too much also.

Comment: Please explain all details in your question that are necessary for an answer. A question can't be too precise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210427/discussion-between-tau-and-juan).

Answer (score 0):

The following pseudocode could rasterize a blob:

```py
def cubeAt(pos):
  height = noise(pos)*magnitude + 1 - distance(pos, center)/radius
  if height > threshold:
    makeFullCube(pos)
  elif height > 0:
    makeHalfCube(pos)

for x in range(0, xsize):
  for y in range(0, ysize):
    cubeAt(vec(x,y))
```

Comment: With the current vagueness of the question, I really can't provide anything more specific.